# Wordpress CSS Stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress

I haven't worked with wordpress for about a year and it seems I have forgot absolutely everything. Can someone please help?

I have just made a custom theme and activated it. However, it making reference to the style.css file.

This is the code in the style.css file:

```
p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 300px;
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php  get_header(); 

 ?>

<h1> hello world </h1>

 <p> work work work work </p>
 <?php

 if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

 the_title();
  endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?><?php

 get_footer();  ?>
```

Functions.php:

```
<?php
function enqueueingStyleSheet() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueingStyleSheet')

?>
```

UPDATE: Still no solution to this. I don't understand how it can be server caching - there are no add-ons or anything that can cause this. I installed Wordpress through Plesk and cant find anything option there to change caching settings. I have no plug-ins on the WordPress installation.

Comment: what seems to be the problem? function `get_stylesheet_uri()` retrieves the stylesheet `style.css` file at the theme's root location.

Comment: That nothing I put the style.css file changes anything. The text in the paragraph is not changed. Also when I inspect in google chrome there is no reference to a stylesheet. Style.css is in the root folder of the theme.

Comment: Where is your server located? Did you disable caching on the server and on your browser?

Comment: No caching issue on the browser. Not sure about the server. I guess not though because the site updates when I change the php files.

Comment: Thats not the case since php files are dynamic, they are most likely ignored by the cache (by default), while the css files are static and usually cached automatically. See if you can log into the control panel to purge the cache, and make sure your browser cache is disabled through the inspector. If you are desperate to try out the css code, just modify the sources folder in the inspector.

Comment: I dont know if that is risky for me. I am running it on a subdomain which shares a dedicated server with a website that gets 1 million views per month. Would it mess things up for the other website if I clear purge the cache?

Comment: You shouldn't have to call that function for the stylesheet. WordPress automatically includes that file on the site. You can check it by going to developer tools and see if the styles.css file is embedded in the head.

Comment: Would definitely hurt the speed but nothing permanent, wouldn't recommend it without consulting the admin. Would perform some checks as @RBCunhaDesign suggested